# How to recognize the change of json's value automacally by using js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making an web application which visualize the change of dynamically changing data. the data is formed by json which have two keys and two values(float Number and `Date()`). the value is changed not regularly but almost every minutes. I want to find the value-change not using js `setInterval()`.

I already tried `setInterval()` but, it's so hard to get actual change. because the cycle of changing json value is not regular. sometimes it's minimum 180ms, maximum 16000ms

the json form is like that....

```
{
  key : 10,
  time : /*new Date()*/
}
```

the result should be like

```
current value : 20 (updated 2019.4.19 11:01)
the difference is +10
```

Comment: Where your json comes from ? Without setinterval you can check for changes every time you fetch the json

Comment: You don't have any json in your code. This is object literals. "the value is changed" how? Does it replace entire object or update properties?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini the json is come from public API. `http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/index.json`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko the propertied doesn't change. only two values of each keys changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects.

Essentially, a proxy is a wrapper around an object, but with predefined getters and setters for all properties. You can create a proxy as follows:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    set(target, propName, value) {
       console.log(`Method value has changed, previous is ${target[propName]}, next value is ${value}`)
       target[propName] = value;
       return target[propName]; 
    }
})
```

Now you can write any side effects inside the setter and use the proxy object instead of the original object.

```
proxy.a = 7 // will log "Method value has changed, previous is 1, next value is 7"
```